# how to sort words by letters in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table like this...

```
 mytbl(names)values('ron'),('sam'),('john'),('tony')
```

Now,I want to see the words from the `names` column where each word will be sorted by letters in alphabetically ascending order.I'm trying to clarify my requirements more specifically..

I want like this

'ron' will be sorted as 'nor'

'sam' will be sorted as 'ams'

'john' will be sorted as 'hjno'

'tony' will be sorted as 'noty'

and I want see exactly those sorted values as my output.How shall I get that...how should I select from the table to get such output?

Please solve my problem.thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the advantage of doing that? scrambled names?

Comment: yes exactly.How shall I do that?

Comment: did you try any thing,one possibility is by ascii value,of each letter loop through

Comment: I'm really curious, why do you need that, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in pure SQL with the help of a tally(numbers) table which you can easily create and populate like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE tally(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n
```

Now the query

```sql
SELECT names, GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY letter SEPARATOR '') sorted_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT names, MID(names, n.n, 1) letter
    FROM mytbl e JOIN tally n
      ON n.n <= CHAR_LENGTH(names)
) q
 GROUP BY names
```

Output:

```
| NAMES | SORTED_NAME |
|-------|-------------|
|  john |        hjno |
|   ron |         nor |
|   sam |         ams |
|  tony |        noty |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74ad4d/5)** demo